# ionic 3 - Runtime Error function not defined - ReferenceError: function is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick

Tags: html, angular, typescript, ionic2, ionic3

I have a button for which I defined a doLogout function for the onclick property, but everytime I click on that button the following error is shown:

```
Runtime Error function not defined - ReferenceError: function is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick
```

The code is very simple, and I used it in other pages, where the function is called correctly. This is my HTML file:

```
<ion-header>  
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>Logout</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
  <div padding>
  <button ion-button block onclick="doLogout()">Logout</button>
 </div>  
   </ion-content>
```

And this is the ts file:

```
export class LogoutPage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams,
  public api : Api) {
  }


  doLogout(){
       //does something
  }

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ionic2/3 is built on top of Angular2/4 (or just Angular) so the correct way to use the click event would be:

```
<button ion-button block (click)="doLogout()">Logout</button>
```

You can find more information in [Angular docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#event-binding)